# Is there any way to defer HTML5 manifest checking?

Tags: html, google-chrome, application-cache

Given that there is a way to invoke an update directly using window.applicationCache.update(), is there any way to omit the update that is performed automatically by the browser when the page is loaded?

I've been experimenting with offline mode in Google Chrome, and so far it appears that 
1) If a manifest file is specified, it will be loaded, and there is nothing I can do in JavaScript to stop it.
2) If the manifest file has changed, the entire cache is going to be updated, and there is nothing I can do to stop it.

In my experience, window.applicationCache.abort() has no effect regardless of when I invoke it.  I've tried invoking it on the first line of javascript, and in the checking and downloading events, but it always downloads everything.  It may have something to do with timing since the files are small and load very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the [`checking` event](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#event-appcache-checking) and [cancel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) it.  The `abort()` method doesn't come into things until step 17 of the [application cache download process](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#downloading-or-updating-an-application-cache), I don't think you're going to be able to stop the process with it.

Comment: preventDefault() has no effect.  The event has cancelable=false in Chrome, though the standard requires it to be cancelable.

Comment: @DaveCausey You should [report the bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).

Answer (score 0):

This is a Chrome bug at the time of writing: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=175063 (please vote it up)

Just tried this on iOS Safari:

```
window.applicationCache.addEventListener('checking', function(event) {
   window.applicationCache.abort();
}, false);
```

It works. In Safari debugger console:

> Application Cache download process was aborted.

Chrome ignores the same code.